# Docusign Signature Without Account

Tags: api, docusignapi, account, demo

Is it possible for a user to sign his/her own signature even he/she doesn't have a DocuSign account? In the github code example (https://github.com/docusign/qs-csharp) I found that account id is passed in parameter. So please let me know how it is possible to sign without docusign account. If possible, please share any specific code example/ api link/demo that can be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
the account in this example (accountId parameter) is for the API call. Someone (the sender) has to have an account. But signers of your code do not need to. Again, you specify one accountId, for the overall account and then just have other users sign - they do not need an account.
try this code example - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp but make sure you create your Integration Key and use OAuth correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to try this. I guess that this process does not necessarily send mail to the recipient too but an integrated automation process of single button click will also work to generate signed documents of predefined users. I am also bit confused of "IK"...can you please explain?

Comment: there are two ways to do that - Embedded Signing (in your app, no email) or Remote Signing  (not in your app - an email with link is sent). You can choose either one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have run the code example mentioned by you successfully. Now I want in  Embedded Signing Ceremony not to have the signing UI in the middle but I want to send all the parameters from code variable at runtime to sign the documents. So in the single button click the targeted docs(may be there will be just a brows popup to upload the pdfs) will be signed and through the download api will be downloaded and only after that we will be able to see the signature on the documents. Is it possible? If yes it will be helpful to have any suggestion regarding the approach.

Comment: can't do that in a single button click. You can use the webhook (Connect) to get a notification in your app when document is signed and download the complete PDF at that point. Or you can redirect back to your app and check if document is signed and download/show it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is multiple documents signing possible in the embedded signing?

Comment: yes, it is. You can have as many documents as you need

Comment: Please, if I answered your question ,marked it as answered. You can always ask additional questions separately.

Comment: Sure. Thanks Inbar.